# Assigning tags to user?

Tags: users, tags

Does anyone know a way (either programmatically or through a plugin) to assign tags to users?

I want to build a list of user interests as tags, so I can match related content to their interests.

Cheers,

Chris.

Comment: ----------
This was just released this month: http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-tags/

Comment: Usually link only answers are considered improvable, but in this case the recommended plugin solution appears to solve the OP's problem. Why not make it a full-fledged answer, @MorganSully?

Comment: Similar question that specifically deals with the complexities of using a user custom taxonomy: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218523/custom-taxonomy-on-users-with-ui/218624#218624

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta

Here is a example of how this can be achieved: http://inchoo.net/wordpress/programatically-add-metadata-to-user-accounts-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure this is quite what I'm looking for. This is because the examples you've given show a one to one relationship between the meta field and value.  I want to able to assign any number of tags to a user. For example if they liked sports the tags associated with their 'interest' fields would be 'football', 'hockey' 'basketball' etc.   

All these fields would be pre-existing post tags that I could assign to the user.  

Does this make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure you're right, user7726, that user meta fields have to be 1-to-1. The codex page says "use the $prev_value parameter to differentiate between meta fields with the same key and user ID."  This seems to imply that users can have multiple entries for "my_tag."  On the other hand, I think you will have to use `add_metadata($meta_type, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique = false)` rather than `update_user_meta`.  By default `add_metadata`  doesn't check whether $user_id already has $meta_key.

Comment: @Chris Carson, isn't it better to use `update_user_meta` if he wants to update this later?

Comment: @user7726 - Are you registering users? Or is the user signing up themselves and they select their interests? Either way, you only need to loop through the selected fields and update / add the fields.

Comment: @Steven I don't think it's possible to do "multiple metas with the same key and user_id" with `update_user_meta`.  I think you have to use the lower-level metadata functions `add_metadata` and `update_metadata`.  I may be wrong.

Comment: @Chris Carson, You are right. But the contents of the value of the interests Meta key could be `interest1,interest2,interest3` and then use `explode` whenever he wants to put it in an array.

Comment: Separately a user meta based solution doesn't have the same benefits as a user taxonomy based solution would. The queries are faster with taxonomies and multi-relationships are supported much better by default. Now if user taxonomies weren't overall crippled...

Answer (score 0):

It's a quite old question, but I'm answering it as it might help other users who come looking for same.

To assign User Tags, you can use the [Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-tags/). Wordpress has built-in support for it, the Plugin allows you to do it the easy way.

Instead of manually registering User Taxonomies, It allows you to directly create the Taxonomies and provides a template for each tag, You can check the demo link here: 
 User Interests:

- [Networking](http://codechutney.com/author/wp_user_interests/networking/)
- [Wordpress](http://codechutney.com/author/wp_user_interests/wordpress/)

You can filter the Title, the listing Or the empty list message as per need using the filters:

- **ut_template_heading**
- **ut_tepmplate_content**
- **ut_template_content_empty**

Answer (score 0):

In terms of a plugin - the Users Insights plugin has a [Groups feature](https://usersinsights.com/wordpress-user-groups/) that works like tags. You can assign multiple groups/tags to each user and you can also search and export the users by their groups/tags.

As for a code solution, as mentioned above the two most common methods are by using taxonomies or user meta, but I wanted to elaborate more on these two approaches as they both have their pros and cons.

The taxonomy approach requires the terms/tags to be created before you assign them to the user:

```php
wp_add_object_terms( $user_id, array($tag1_id, $tag2_id), 'user_tag' )
```

On one side this might introduce a bit more complexity in the code, but on the other it prevents typos and ensures that only existing tags are assigned.

The user meta approach gives you more freedom as you can assign tags dynamically:

```php
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_tag', 'tag-one');
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_tag', 'tag-two');
```

But this approach is prone to typos, as you might store something like "tag-one" or "tag_one" (unless you add some kind of validation).