# Taxonomy Meta Box in User Profile?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, users

Is it possible to have users populate a taxonomy meta box(es), using the post_tag or any custom taxonomies I create?

The idea is to include users in a network into the taxonomy schema, which would bring the community together in a better way.

I guess a more specific way to ask this is how would I add taxonomy meta boxes to the user interface.  Obviously anything's possible if I'm willing to go far enough.

Is this something that can be done using existing WP API's etc?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a similar post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25288/assigning-tags-to-user/139387#139387 and a plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-tags

Comment: Similar question that specifically deals with the complexities of using a user custom taxonomy: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218523/custom-taxonomy-on-users-with-ui/218624#218624

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to link taxonomies and users is to link the user account to a custom post type then link the taxonomy to the custom post type.

**Example:**

[image: User - Post - Taxonomy]

You can use the action [user_register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) to automatically create a new post for every new user and then start linking everything.

I have used this method on https://myyogaavenue.com and it works like a charm.

Comment: ljaas, how did you link the user account to the custom post type to the taxonomy?

Comment: I will provide code for this by the end of this weekend.

Comment: I think, it's more easy to add an input text with "tag1, tag2, tag3…" in user_meta then play with http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 2):

Giving taxonomies to users can be done! Look at this article that i found on the internet… It explain easily how to do it!:-)

http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress#comment-1911972

Comment: This article is pretty old now so hopefully someone will make an up to date tutorial. Ideally the answer here on WPSE would have all the details and not rely on outside links, but in this case the link works.

Comment: WPSE question with updated versions of solutions from justin's post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218523/custom-taxonomy-on-users-with-ui/218624#218624